# Excel interop how to set text direction from left to right

Tags: c#, excel

I need to change text direction (not worbook direction and not text alignment) of specified column.

There is a button that do this functionality in Excel:
[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: After I have reached enough reputation to add an Image of the button, which functionality i need to perfotm in the code, I think that the question is realy understandable and usefull. In any case, i HAVE FOUND AN ANSWER! See below :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found an answer. The property called ReadingOrder

```
             Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
            _Worksheet xlWorksheet = null;

           //Open work sheet
            xlApp.Visible = false;
            xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file, Type.Missing, false);
            xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

            //Gets relevant column
            Range range = (Range)xlWorksheet.get_Range(column, Type.Missing);

            //Set text direction
            range.EntireColumn.ReadingOrder = (int)Constants.xlLTR;

            xlWorkbook.Save();

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from right to the left (change the text direction) then you need to do that in your country settings of Windows or excel, or find a font that goes from right to left.

Comment: There is a button that do it! Because of I can't to add image to my question I can't show it to you